# Why is the electronic configuration of gold written in this order?

Tags: electronic-configuration

This is an example from my chem text.

> Eletronic configuration for $\ce{^79Au}$:
>   $$\ce{1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 4s^2 3d^10 4p^6 5s^2 4d^10 5p^6 \color{red}{4f^14} 5d^10 \color{red}{6s^1}}$$
>   (Emphasis mine)

If I would follow the Linus Pauling diagram, I might write it as "$\ce{5p^6 6s^1 4f^14}$" rather than the example above. Why does the $\ce{6s^1}$ jump to the last position in the line?

Comment: I found a solution for myself. It happens because I had to withdraw the remaining electrons from the most energized layers, thus, I have to put it in evidence. I'm not sure if I delete the question or not. It's my first time here.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have prettified your post a little. If you have found the solution, you can add it as the answer below (it should be a little more elaborate than that one line though) and accept it, there is no need to delete your question.